# Django Channels 2.4 ... do WebSocket messages always arrive in order

Tags: django, websocket, django-channels

Given a single client with a WebSocket connection to Daphne/Channels 2.4, are messages guaranteed to arrive in order that they are sent from the client?

Answer (score 0):

On the server side yes the order is stable. However you client might not have a stable order, there is no promise that web browsers for example will maintain a stable order.